Can you safely update a Django AppConfig.label?
I'm in the process of merging two Django projects however they have conflicting app names.
For example, the conflicting app names are customer, order, and product which are categorized into ecommerce and wholesale subdirectories.
project
├── manage.py
├── apps
│   └── ecommerce
    │   └── customer
    │   └── order
    │   └── product
    └── wholesale
    │   └── customer
    │   └── order
    │   └── product

It's clearly stated in the docs for AppConfig.label that changing the label after migrations have been applied will cause breaking changes.
I've tried creating an empty migration to manually rename the table then update the Model Meta app_label option however that seems to cause breaking changes as well.
migrations.AlterModelOptions(
    name='Product',
    options={'app_label': 'wholesale_product'},
),
migrations.AlterModelTable(
    name='Product',
    table='wholesale_product_product',
),

I feel like it should be easy to just rename the table. What's the best way to solve the name conflicts? Is there a way to do it without having to rename the apps and moving the models?

You can actually change the label of your app
apps/ecommerce/customer/apps.py
class CustomerConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "apps.ecommerce.customer"
    label = "ecommerce_customer" # You can also remove this to use the default -customer label
apps/wholesale/customer/apps.py
class CustomerConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "apps.wholesale.customer"
    label = "wholesale_customer"

Remember to change your installed_apps in settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS=[
...
"apps.wholesale.customer",
"apps.ecommerce.customer",
...
]

Also in you project urls.py
urlpatterns = [
 path("ecommerce/customers/", include("apps.ecommerce.customer.urls")),
 path("wholesale/customers/", include("apps.wholesale.customer.urls")),
]

About renaming the existing table I would suggest you try using raw sql following that the model has moved from one app to another
ALTER TABLE oldapp_mymodel RENAME TO newapp_mymodel;

Then you can makemigrations for your apps and fake them by doing the followong
python manage.py makemigrations old_app
python manage.py migrate old_app --fake

